# How to host multiple low traffic websites on ec2?

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-ec2

We have about 30 websites with almost no traffic (<~10 visits/day) which are currently hosted on a dedicated server.

We are evaluating hosting on Amazon EC2 however I'm not sure how to do that properly.

- One (micro) instance per website is too expensive
- ~10 websites on one instance (using apache virtual hosts) make auto-scaling impossible (or at least difficult)

Or is cloud computing not suitable for such a use-case?

Comment: This question is more about *how* to host multiple websites on a single ec2, not about choosing the hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason i would do this is to decrease costs.

If i were to do it, i would try all 10 on a micro instance and see how smoothly it runs, if its causing problems, move them to a small instance, that should be plenty to handle ~300visits/day (30websites * 10visits/day).

And with this few of requests, you shouldnt worry about auto-scalling at the moment.
If they get higher traffic you can get them there own small instance. (although it may be a bit of a pain to move a site, but its not the end of the world)